# Laravel keeps returning "419 Page Expired" on POST requests in reverse proxy setup

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, mitmproxy

In order to create a production alike development setup we set the local dev environment with a ssl-terminating reverse proxy up using [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org) and docker-compose. So the schematics of our setup looks like this:

```
                       :443             :8000
 ┌───────────┐         ┌───────┐        ┌─────┐
 │ localhost ├─────────┤ proxy ├────────┤ app │
 └───────────┘         └───▲───┘        └─────┘
  dns mimicry via          │
  /etc/hosts:           upstream: http://app:8000

  localhost.dev 127.0.0.1
```

So i access the app surfing to `https://localhost.dev` which is successful being upstreamed by mitmproxy (in reverse operating mode) to `http://app:8000`.

The i guess most important env variables are set as follows:

```yaml
APP_URL: https://localhost.dev
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS: localhost.dev,app,localhost
SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
SESSION_COOKIE: dev
SESSION_DOMAIN: .localhost.dev
```

Every kind of request works fine, but all `POST` requests fail. We did not mix up the web- and api-middleware, so the issue is we actually can't login in the dev environment because the Blade based login-request:

```
POST http://localhost.dev:8000/signin HTTP/2.0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language:    de-DE,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
accept-encoding:    gzip, deflate, br
content-type:   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length: 103
origin: https://localhost.dev
referer:    https://localhost.dev/signin
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IjczeWNlSkpQQz<...>
cookie: dev=eyJpdiI6Im9nTFNDZ3IvVWxtVlNQW<...>
cookie: 6z6cjWPCXukcTJxmZr9QvJyFEraMhksxP<...>
cookie: _pk_id.39.560d=8d63f5a6d47b0b9a.1633971639.
cookie: _pk_ses.39.560d=1
cookie: mtm_consent=1633971639118
cookie: hasConsent=true
cookie: FCGnj1jUBGwy2ndzVUK45gGCWyB1rqgWZ<...>
upgrade-insecure-requests:  1
sec-fetch-dest: document
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
sec-gpc:    1
te: trailers
X-Forwarded-Proto:  https
_token:   dEmnQkCa6bq7E30M30BBKbqm815WoG9V17<...>
email:    me@this.com
password: 123456
```

fails:

```
HTTP/1.1 419 unknown status
Host:   localhost.dev
Date:   Mon, 11 Oct 2021 17:01:07 GMT
Connection: close
X-Powered-By:   PHP/7.4.24
Cache-Control:  no-cache, private
date:   Mon, 11 Oct 2021 17:01:07 GMT
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: dev=eyJpdiI6IlVpUzNid0xIbjRPT<...>; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-2021 19:01:07 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost.dev; httponly; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: x1UxyIEmxnJDgdt7e5hVCvjSwD0J5<...>; expires=Mon, 11-Oct-2021 19:01:07 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=localhost.dev; httponly; samesite=lax
```

<sup>I snipped (`<...>`) hopefully useless gibberish.</sup>

I tried multiple different combinations of domains and config settings - all keeps failing. I would be very thankful for any hint why this keeps failing.

Feel free to request any further information.

###### TrustedProxies.php

```php
protected $proxies = "*";
protected $headers =
  RequestAlias::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR |
  RequestAlias::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST |
  RequestAlias::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT |
  RequestAlias::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO;
```

Comment: Does this help: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies?

Comment: Thank you very much @Rwd - i of course forgot to put the trusted proxies setting into the question. But i guess setting `$proxies` to `*` should be okay?

Comment: Yeah, you can absolutely set `$proxies` to `*`. It's just an added security step to add specific IPs if you know what they are. Please note that, in some cases, it will be the private IP address or the proxy and not the public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investing lots of time i was able to pin this down to the following symptom:

The request did only contain one of the sent cookies. Which one was somehow random, but it was **never** the session cookie.

Therefore the session could not be reused and was "started" every request.

#### mitmproxy in reverse mode has likely a bug

I removed mitmproxy from the stack and added Caddy instead:

###### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
# ...
  proxy:
    image: caddy:latest
    cap_add:
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    volumes:
      - .reverse/Caddyfile:/etc/caddy/Caddyfile
      - .reverse/data:/data
    ports:
      - "443:443"
# ...
```

###### .reverse/Caddyfile

```
https://localhost.dev {
  tls internal
  reverse_proxy http://app:8000
}
```

After installing the issued cert (`.reverse/data/caddy/cerificates/pki/authorities/local/root.crt`) in the browser everything worked like a charm.

I would state that **mitmproxy** does **not** pass all cookies from the request.